# ShareDaialog in listview in customadapter

Tags: android, share, custom-adapter

every element in the listview contains name image and description there is a share button on every item on listview that share through facebook i`m using this code in getview function and it give me error in this what should i suppose to use instead of this

```
 ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
```

in the getview:

```
 final LayoutHandler layoutHandler;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        final View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row, parent, false);
        layoutHandler=new LayoutHandler();
        // Find Views
        ListView listView = (ListView)row.findViewById(R.id.lv);
        final RatingBar ratingBar= (RatingBar) row.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
        TextView rowTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.nam);
        TextView rowDescription = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.idd);
        //  ListView lv = (ListView)MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.li);
        final ImageView imageview = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageV);
        layoutHandler.favoriteImg = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imgbtn_favorite);
        layoutHandler.shareimage = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.share);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);

        CallbackManager callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);

        shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>(){

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result){
                Log.d("d", "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException error){
                Log.d("d", "error");
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel(){
                Log.d("d", "cancel");
            }
        });
```

Comment: Change to :  ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(yourActivity.this);

Comment: I tried that it said can not resolve constractor ShareDialog(Activityname);

Comment: you have to create your dialog with : `Activityname.this`

Comment: can you give me more detailes Ahmed ,please read my previous comment

Comment: if you are inside an inner class of an Activity, you have to use `ShareDialog shareDialog = new ShareDialog(yourActivity.this);` , if not you have to use the `getBaseContext()`.  You need to verify that you are using the main UI thread.